# how to remove valvoline wiper blades on 2014 honda civic

Tags: honda, civic, windshield-wipers, sedan

[image]

[image]

ive been looking up tutorials on how to remove wiper blades and none of them seem to apply...

locking tab... couldnt find one. rotate blade perpendicular to arm... couldnt. rotate blade 45 degrees and pull down... couldnt.

i have a 2014 honda civic sedan and i got my blades changed at valvoline. anyone familar with how to remove these wiper?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i managed to figure this out. there is a little upward arrow on the left hand side of the ridge part that indicates that it is to be pulled up and to the right. it's like a little cover that you can open. from there you can remove it with the old turn the wiper perpendicular to the blade arm and shove it down method. -_-, why do wiper manufacturers have to make so many different ways of attaching these darn things

Comment: To test your intelligence - time is a factor :). :)

Comment: No, really glad you have it sorted, best of luck.

Comment: so am i :P. it was extremely frustrating there for a while. first time changing the wipers haha, it was dark and very cold too and i had to keep ducking back in my car cause my hands kept freezing up. think i stripped the paint off partially on the wiper arm trying to rotate the blade too much, cracked the assembly on the old wiper blade too. oh well, you live and you learn. finally got new wipers on :-]

Answer (score 2):

Insert a small screwdriver between the wiperarm and the ridged piece. Pry the ridged piece up. With the arm away from the windshield tap on the end of the blade. This should release the wiper from the "J" hook on the end of the arm.

Comment: if you look at the side pic though you can see that the ridge piece fits with the metal part like two puzzle pieces coming together... i don't think you can move it... are you sure? should i do it from the top end or the bottom end?

Answer (score 1):

We Honda owners have bayonet mount arms. the blades are removed via (usually) squeezing a clip near the pivot and pulling back towards the arm. in many cases you have to rotate the blade assy. to fully remove it. The end of the arm is a hook, and this is why pulling back is needed. the clip that you squeeze might be hard to see but a good rule of thumb here is to look at the new blade replacement to see where the slip is located on it and compare to the one on the car.

Answer (score 0):

Those blades look like you should rotate the blade so it forms a “T” with the arm, then push the blade down onto the arm and it should slide off - there may be a small clip inside the hook part of the arm which you should see if you look, which needs to be released.

If all else fails then cut the blade but don’t damage the arm...

Comment: i tried to do just that, if u look in pic two with that ridged clip though. the clip is stopping it from rotating more than like 30 degrees towards the clip. i also looked underneath for something to push on and theres something there but its got a weird design. its like flush with the underside naturally so u cant really push it down any further. i tried to take a pic but couldnt

Comment: Some don’t have a tab to move : you just have to give a sharp push down... Or just cut it off...